# 衰えるという言葉の由来は何ですか?

Tags: nuances, history

For instance, とじる and しめる.
とじる means an activity or a show has finished so "the door is closed". This word is used in ending or closing something like 傘をとじる, 本をとじる.

しめる means to tie the bag tight with a string. So this word is used as "keep something away" or "Don't let something out". For example, 窓をしめる, 鍋の蓋をしめる.

I am wondering what's the history of 衰える.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have an academic interest about the ancient etymology of this word? Do you know a bit about archaic Japanese [like this](https://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E7%AB%B9%E5%8F%96%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E5%9C%8B%E6%B0%91%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB))? Or do you simply want to understand the nuance of this word better?

Comment: I think it's nuance. The reason why I asked this is because I saw a article written by a Japanese before. He/She (I'm not sure) explained those words like this. So I thought maybe all of words can be explained like this. Because the way the hiragana sound doesn't mean anything to me, as a foreigner, so I find it's more easy to remember words with this type of explanation. However, this type of explanation might is just depending on someone's feeling as a native-speaker rather than the ancient etymology.

Answer (score 4):

### The etymology: historical derivation

衰【おとろ】える comes from earlier 衰【おとろ】へる.  This is the regular shift to 下一段活用【しもいちだんかつよう】 conjugation of earlier 下二段活用【しもにだんかつよう】 verb 衰【おとろ】ふ.  For more about this verb conjugation pattern, see [the Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8), or more briefly, [the English Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8#Japanese).

衰【おとろ】ふ itself derives from 劣【おと】る in the less-common //o// variant of the 未然形【みぜんけい】 (irrealis form) + suffix ふ that indicates repetition, ongoing action, or continued change.

So:

- 劣【おと】る: "to decline in money or amount, to make a loss; to be lesser, to be inferior" →
- おとろ + ふ → 衰【おとろ】ふ: "to be continuously lesser: to become lesser, to become weaker, to be in ongoing decline" →
- 衰【おとろ】へる: regular 下一段 shift
- 衰【おとろ】える: regular shift where mid-word //h//'s disappear

#### Sources

- Shogakukan's 国語大辞典: dead tree version
- Daijisen and Daijirin: entries for 衰える available online via Kotobank [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A1%B0%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-453573)

Comment: Great, I found [a source to support this](https://bit.ly/2NQCsyJ).

Comment: @naruto: Apologies, I should have noted my sources -- I just added those to the post.  There may be more than one origin; ふ is usually 四段, so the 下二段 variant may be either a shift in sense to the realis, or a separate derivation.  The KDJ suggests that this ふ might derive from verb 経【ふ】, which was 下二段; however, that then raises the question of why the auxiliary ふ is 四段.  Another theory is that this ふ is from あふ (相【あ】ふ、合【あ】ふ), but that meaning seems not to match.  More about ふ [at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B5-614866) and [at Weblio](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5).

Comment: @naruto, I'm curious if you've ever run across a source discussing the apparent cognacy of 劣る・落とす・落ちる.  Underlying verb おつ: 上一段 form → おちる, rare //o// 未然形 + causative す → おとす, rare //o// 未然形 + stative る (perhaps related to あり?) → おとる.

Answer (score 3):

The main meaning of 衰える is "to go into a decline"; it's used with someone or something which was *once strong or prosperous*. It's typically used with things like a falling country, a human being (physically or socially), a typhoon.

I could not find the etymology of 衰える on the net, but [this word existed 1000 years ago](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D%E3%81%B5). A large dictionary about archaic Japanese may have some speculation about the history, but I doubt it will help you understand the nuance. (I suspect you are expecting something interesting [like this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86#Etymology), but the etymology of 衰える is probably not that interesting or intuitive...)